# Checking if a Git branch has been merged into master when SQUASHED?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, squash

I'd like to automate cleaning of remote branches. I want to be able to check to see if a branch has been merged into master already. Originally, my plan was to use git merge-base to see the last common commit.

However, it turns out that we squash all of our branches as we merge them into master. As this creates a new commit hash, I'm unable to find the common commits between master and my branches.

How might I go about determining if a branch has been merged if we've squashed them all when merging?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not exactly reliable but `git log --grep="merge $BRANCH"` or something might work, if you put the branch name in the commit messages when you do the squash merge.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't always put the name of the branch in the commit messages when we do the squash merge.

Comment: Are you gaining anything by squashing?  You could always squash via rebase first and then do a normal merge.

Comment: That's just the established work flow, unfortunately.

Comment: There are 2 built in ways you can track history with Git - one is via reachability, the other is via patch-id.  Unfortunately, your workflow breaks your ability to use either of those techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

1. Use the GitHub API to get the HEAD SHA for all merged pull requests.
2. Match these SHAs against local branches.

If a local branch's HEAD has corresponds to that of a PR that's been merged, then you can safely delete it. This will work regardless of how the PR was merged (full merge, fast foward, squash and merge).

I implemented this approach in a [delete-squashed-branches](https://gist.github.com/danvk/a715357444ff3c1a05c4cff730eea8e1) script. Here's what usage looks like:

```
(master) $ git branch
  delete-merged-prs
  fixup
  unmerged-branch
* master

(master) $ delete-squashed-branches
Finding local branches which were merged onto origin/master via GitHub...
warning: deleting branch 'delete-merged-prs' that has been merged to
     'refs/remotes/origin/delete-merged-prs', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch delete-merged-prs (was 325a42b).
warning: deleting branch 'fixup' that has been merged to
     'refs/remotes/origin/fixup', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch fixup (was e54f54b).

(master) $ git branch
  unmerged-branch
* master
```

(The warnings can be ignored since the branches were merged onto master via Squash & Merge.)

Caveats:

- You'll need to `pip install pygithub` to use the script.
- It will look for local branches that were merged onto `origin/(current branch)`. So you'll want to run it on `master`, `develop` or whatever branch you work off of.
- If you have multiple long-lived branches, this approach won't work very well.

Comment: Honestly, this is the only good solution in the long run.   Squashed merges on a busy repo spit out merge conflicts all day long.

Comment: I made some modifications that allow for git:// uris and private repos, and --force delete.  https://gist.github.com/earonesty/4986c7009cfc289323a5fc2516320797

Answer (score 2):

You could do an experimental merge and check whether it introduces any changes, like so:

```
git checkout -b foo-merge-test-branch master
git merge --squash foo
if [ -n "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then 
  echo "foo has not been merged";
else 
  echo "foo is already merged";
fi
git reset --hard && git checkout master && git branch -d foo-merge-test-branch
```

This will only work if none of the files changed in the original `git merge --squash foo` have seen further conflicting changes on `master` since then.