# Check if git branch has been incorporated into other branch without running `git merge`

Tags: git, git-merge

I have featurue branches that I squash before merging into the integration branch. Sometimes I have random feature branches lying around and I cannot remember if they were merged into the integration branch.

The problem, is that if I run `git merge` to check, sometimes this will cause problems for feature branches that have *already* been merged + squashed into the integration branch. (If someone can explain exactly what this problem is, that would be nice, I assume it's because the squash and merge creates an extra commit).

So how can I check if a branch has already been merged without running `git merge`?

Comment: `git branch --[no-]merged`?

Comment: thanks can you give a complete example with 2 branches? I will upvote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a Git branch has been merged into master when SQUASHED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260574/checking-if-a-git-branch-has-been-merged-into-master-when-squashed)

Comment: eh I am not seeing any good answers on that @AndrewC, do you see any?

Comment: I'm afraid that's because there aren't any good answers to your problem that I know of.

Comment: How did you squash and merge? By `git merge --squash` or `git rebase -i` or `git reset --soft && git commit`?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the diff of your branch against the integration branch.  If it is already merged there will be no changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17618008/498699

You can use `...` to only show the changes on one branch as compared to the other.

So your command would be `git diff <integration branch>...<feature branch>`. If the diff is empty then the branches were merged together otherwise they weren't.